# nginx RTMP , dash

Tags: video-streaming, rtmp, mpeg-dash, dash.js

I am using rtmpNginx to create Dash.
I got segmets created:

```
[SND]   1464729671819-init.m4a  31-May-2016 23:55   557  
[   ]   1464729671819-init.m4v  31-May-2016 23:55   659  
[SND]   1464729671819-raw.m4a   01-Jun-2016 00:13   0    
[   ]   1464729671819-raw.m4v   01-Jun-2016 00:13   34K  
[   ]   1464729671819.mpd
```

in my /dash folder

Then I try to play it with https://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/dash.all.min.js player

```
<video data-dashjs-player autoplay src="/dash/1464729671819.mpd" controls></video>
```

and got these logs in my console:

```
279] Manifest updated... set new data on buffers. 
Debug.js:108 [5279] Added 0 inline events 
Debug.js:108 [5280] Refresh manifest in 4.999 seconds. 
Debug.js:108 [10416] Parsing complete: ( xml2json: 1ms, objectiron: 1ms, total: 0.002s) 
Debug.js:108 [10417] Manifest has been refreshed at Wed Jun 01 2016 00:14:00 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été))[1464732840.361]  
Debug.js:108 [10418] SegmentTimeline detected using calculated Live Edge Time 
Debug.js:108 [10418] Manifest updated... set new data on buffers. 
Debug.js:108 [10419] Added 0 inline events 
Debug.js:108 [10420] Refresh manifest in 4.999 seconds. 
Debug.js:108 [15523] Parsing complete: ( xml2json: 1ms, objectiron: 1ms, total: 0.002s) 
Debug.js:108 [15523] Manifest has been refreshed at Wed Jun 01 2016 00:14:05 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été))[1464732845.467]  
Debug.js:108 [15523] SegmentTimeline detected using calculated Live Edge Time 
Debug.js:108 [15523] Manifest updated... set new data on buffers. 
Debug.js:108 [15524] Added 0 inline events 
Debug.js:108 [15524] Refresh manifest in 5 seconds.
```

But nothing is playing !

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which nginx-rtmp are you using? If you are using the original, see https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/issues/614 for why. You can use https://github.com/sergey-dryabzhinsky/nginx-rtmp-module instead, which has a fix applied and is known to work with dash.js.

Comment: I use the original one, since I could not compile the fork !